# How do you write a CSS selector when the class name is just an integer?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's say I have

```
<span class="1">hello</span>
```

And I want to declare:

```
span.1 { /* rules */ }
```

This does not seem to work (i.e. the CSS rule is not being applied.)  Is there a way to get this to work?  I tried just quoting the "1" in the CSS selector but that doesn't appear to be it.

Comment: `1` is not a valid CSS class name. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this: [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names)

> a (class) name must begin with an underscore (_), a dash (-), or a letter(a–z)

Answer (score 4):

You should always name your classes and IDs with semantics in mind. What meaning does a number bring to anybody? What does it count?

To avoid this, having IDs and classes named as just integers isn't [valid CSS according to W3](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/), and thus not supported by most browsers. Always validate your HTML and CSS.

The solution is to simply give your class a more meaningful name. What are you counting? Is it comments on a blog? If so, you could just add the class `comment` to each of them. If you really need unique name for each, you could use `comment5` instead, but that doesn't seem to make much sense as a class, in which case you should be using IDs instead.

The exact naming requirements is also described in [W3C's CSS specification, section 4.1.3 Characters and case](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters):

> In CSS, *identifiers* (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); **they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit**. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

Comment: I'm counting categories of characters, where each category is styled differently.  The program generating the HTML simply increments a counter for each new category that is encountered.  That's how I ended up with class names consisting of an integer (I see now that prepending "_" or some such is the answer.)  ID's aren't really an option because there are multiple characters in each category.

Comment: Prepending `_` will not make it more semantic. Why not name them by their category? Not just a number representing the category. Or at the very least, prepend them with `category`.

Answer (score 3):

So you should check [CSS Grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner)

**so name must begin with an underscore _ ,letter(a–z), followed by any number of dashes, underscores, letters, or numbers.**

**EDIT:**
I recommend to you read this article [Valid chars in CSS class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names).
Colleague **@Triptych** gave us awesome answer.

Comment: Not true. An identifier cannot begin with a dash, and then be followed by one, e.g. `--foo` is not a valid class name.